# How to call a function from views.py to tasks.py?

Tags: django, django-views, celery

I'm trying this: but its throwing an `TypeError: auto_sms() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'` error.

Now I'm thinking of getting the function from views.py instead and calling it on tasks.py if `requests` is not working on tasks.py, how can I do it? Thanks!

```
@shared_task
def auto_sms(request):
    responses = Rainfall.objects.filter(
        level='Torrential' or 'Intense',
        timestamp__gt=now() - timedelta(days=1),
    )

    count = responses.count()
    if not (count % 10) and count > 0:
        send_sms(request)

    return
```

Comment: how exactly are you calling your task

Comment: btw thanks for commenting but I just forgot to import `request` from `django.http` that's why it's not working before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the entire `request` is probably not a good idea since it can include Django model objects such as a user object. Now the problem that you will face is that if there is an object that is not serializable, then you'll get an error while calling the function. So instead of passing the whole `request`, just send the data that you actually need.

For example, I'm guessing you need the user here to send an SMS to. So instead of passing the whole request with the user object included, then just send the `user_id` and then get the user there. basically, you have to make sure that the data you're passing is serializable.

It's generally a good idea to pass ids of the Django models since the data might change while your function is being processed and you might get the old data if you pass the whole data.